# Create Windows DSN using python3

Tags: python, database, windows, odbc

Is it possible to create ODBC data source in windows using python 3?

Following statement runs successfully with python2 but not with python3, why? ODBCCP32 is available only in py2?

`ctypes.windll.ODBCCP32.SQLConfigDataSource(0, 4, "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)", 'Uid="Admin"\x00DESCRIPTION="pyscript"\x00DSN="PYTEST"\x00pwd=""\x00DBQ="C:\\pytest.mdb"')`

Comment: What's the error, if any?

Comment: on python3 it returns 0. at first I thought it's because I've installed 64bit python and were trying to create 64bit ms access data source, but i've reinstalled 32bit python 3 and data source still can't be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't working because all strings in python3 are unicode strings by default.

So I had to convert it to 'bytes' object liket this:
`ctypes.windll.ODBCCP32.SQLConfigDataSource(0, 4, bytes('Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)', 'iso-8859-1'), bytes('Uid=Admin\x00DESCRIPTION=pyscript\x00DSN=PYTEST\x00pwd=\x00DBQ=C:\\pytest.mdb', 'iso-8859-1'))`

Comment: I can't seem to find docs on this function. Is there any way you can provide a breakdown on the parameters? So far I've got `SQLConfigDataSource( ?? int, ?? int, driver bytes, parameters bytes)`. I guess the question is, what do the `int`s mean?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlconfigdatasource-function